# Reading data from a continuously updating log file

Tags: c

I have a log file (similar to a web server's access log) which I need to continuously read and use a regular expression to fetch a value in each line.

For example, if you could imagine reading from a web server's access log, I would be getting the IP address of each visitor as their visit is written to the log.

Of course this is easy to do using the linux command line (combination of tail and sed, or something like that), but I want to do it using C code.

I guess I could open the file, read X lines, save the number of the last line I read, and then on the next round open the file, move to the line X, and read from there, and so on, but this seems very clumsy.

Is there a known way or best practice for reading data from a continuously updating log file?

Thanks

Comment: You should not close the file and just wait for new data, will your file rotate ?
You can check https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tail.c

Comment: You could find the source code for the GNU or BSD implementation of tail and either modify it to do what you need directly or at least learn how they do it.

Comment: you can read stuff about inotify